# How to get data of channel in PyAudio

Tags: python, playback, pyaudio

I want to get data of left and right channels from sound data in PyAudio. I have 1D shape array and don't know which of them are from channels

I tried to change the first half of data to zero. I have silence.
I tried to change each second number to zero. I have silence.
In documentation I saw that PyAudio has a parameter "output_channels". I think it has more than one output channel.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
CHUNK = 102
WIDTH = 2
#CHUNK = 10404
#RATE = 192000
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            output=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
frames_per_buffer = 44100
data=[]
n=0
a=np.zeros(CHUNK*CHANNELS*WIDTH)
for i in range(1000):
    data.append(stream.read(CHUNK))
    for m in range(CHUNK):
        a[m]=data[0][m]
    s_0=[]
    for m in range(int(CHUNK*CHANNELS*WIDTH)):
        s_0.append(int(data[0][m]))
    a=np.asarray(s_0)
    a=a.reshape(int(CHUNK*WIDTH), 2)
    a_T = np.transpose(a)
    a_T[1][:] = 0
    a = np.transpose(a_T)
    a = a.reshape(CHUNK*CHANNELS*WIDTH)
    s_2=[]
    for m in range(CHUNK*CHANNELS*WIDTH):
        s_2.append(int(a[m]))
    sound=[bytes(s_2)]
    stream.write(sound.pop(0), CHUNK)
    data=[]
print('s_0')
s_0[0:20]
print('s_2')
s_2[0:20]
```

Sound doesn't play if I change data

Answer (score 2):

This works to get channel0 from a stereo file:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
chunk = 1024

# open up a wave
wf = wave.open('/home/jeremy/Music/440.wav', 'rb')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
RATE = wf.getframerate()    
# open stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
channels = wf.getnchannels()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = channels,
                rate = RATE,
                output = True)
# read some data
data = wf.readframes(chunk)
while len(data) == chunk*swidth*channels:
    # write data out to the audio stream
    stream.write(data)
    indata = np.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
    # deinterleave, select 1 channel
    channel0 = indata[0::channels]
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
if data:
    stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: anyway it plays two channels

Comment: the channel0 data is in channel0, you can use that for output (change the channel0 back into str and send that in stream.write() instead of data)  OR you could try using channels=1 in the stream definition if all you care about is playing one channel and accessing the raw data is not relevant